# Fail in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i want to put this code in my website, but when i try to click on the menu button in Firefox it pops up then the background changes from the normal color to white (or is gone).

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/3pn2pkt6/19/

```js
$('.toggle-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('h4.toggle-menu').text($(this).text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');
   
    $('.circle').toggleClass('Opacity');
    $('#overlay-menu').delay(5000).toggleClass('Opacity');
    $('.circle').toggleClass('open');
    
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fffdee;
}

.circle {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #98694d;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;  
}

.open {
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}

#overlay-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 4;
}

h4.toggle-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 70px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
}

.Opacity {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>

<nav id="home-menu" class="menu">
     <h4 class="toggle-menu">Menu</h4>
</nav>

<div id="overlay-menu"><p>MY CONTENT</p></div>
```

Comment: works identically in firefox 52/54 as with any other browser ... `it pops up` - what pops up?

Comment: if you try to open the menu the brown background will show during the animation but then it will hide.

Comment: My apologies - it works in firefox 54, but **not** in firefox 52 (I must've tested in 54 twice!) - clearly a behaviour change is coming in firefox

Comment: You mention Firefox but not other browsers. Does that mean the code *does* work in Chrome, IE, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This works: (small change in the .open-class (added the opacity to it)), and removal of one line in the JS. Tested in Firefox and Chrome

```js
$('.toggle-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('h4.toggle-menu').text($(this).text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');
   
    //$('.circle').toggleClass('Opacity');
    $('#overlay-menu').delay(5000).toggleClass('Opacity');
    $('.circle').toggleClass('open');
    
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fffdee;
}

.circle {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #98694d;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;  
}

.open {
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
   opacity: 1;
}

#overlay-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 4;
}

h4.toggle-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 70px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
}

.Opacity {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>

<nav id="home-menu" class="menu">
     <h4 class="toggle-menu">Menu</h4>
</nav>

<div id="overlay-menu"><p>MY CONTENT</p></div>
```